# Fetch the "Last Ran At" time for a quartz job

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Is there an API to determine the last execution time of a quartz job.

Thanks,
Sandhya

Answer (score 10):

Strictly speaking, a Job doesn't have a fire time, a Trigger does.  And Trigger has getPreviousFireTime().  See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getPreviousFireTime%28%29

If your Job has multiple triggers, you can retrieve them all and examine their fire times.  See the cookbook examples at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/cookbook/index.html

Comment: Its worth noting this isn't actually 100% accurate; triggers which are not periodic (eg. `WithSimpleSchedule`) are not preserved (they are deleted after executing); all you'll get back this way is the last time *a currently active trigger* executed the job; which may or may not be the last time the job was actually executed.

Comment: @Doug: Any idea if there is a way to keep an expired trigger or some trick/workaround?

Comment: @Rev1.0 Nope. As far as I can tell the only way of doing this is by manually keeping track of it when the task executes (personally I use an in memory sqlite database specifically for this purpose).

Comment: links does not work

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that the "last execution time" is needed inside the overriden `executeInternal` or `execute` method that your job has. The `JobExecutionContext` that it gets as a parameter already provides the method [`getPreviousFireTime()`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.2/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getPreviousFireTime) which is the Previous Fire Time of the most recent trigger that fired and executed your Job.